# psycopg2: ERROR occured!!! rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not load the output GDAL driver

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to query a raster from a database using python. By doing so, I always receive the following exception: **ERROR occured!!! rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not load the output GDAL driver**. This error is confusing, I activated all drivers in the corresponding database with `SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';`

If I execute the same commands using psql, everything works fine.

My python env looks as follows:

certifi==2021.10.8
GDAL==3.4.2
pip==21.2.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
setuptools==58.0.4
wheel==0.37.1

Using `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

example for reproduction:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import psycopg2 as db

connection = db.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable as (SELECT ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1, 5), 10), 10, 10, '8BUI', 1) AS rast);""")
connection.commit()
# Use a virtual memory file, which is named like this
vsipath = '/vsimem/from_postgis'
# Download raster data into Python as GeoTIFF, and make a virtual file for GDAL
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_AsGDALRaster(rast, 'GTiff') FROM mytable;")
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vsipath, bytes(cursor.fetchone()[0]))
# Read first band of raster with GDAL
ds = gdal.Open(vsipath)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
    
# Close and clean up virtual memory file
ds = band = None
gdal.Unlink(vsipath)
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out my problem. The solution is stated [here](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html). By using `SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';` the raster drivers are enabled for the current session only! The following will enable it for all sessions:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```